# htaccess RewriteRule different variables

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, variables, mod-rewrite

How do i rewrite `/blog/?p=1` to `/en/post.html` and `/blog/?tag=event` to `/en/tags.html` whilst the variables are still accesible?

I used this before:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/?$    /en/tags.html  [QSA,L]
```

But then I had to also rewrite a different variable that is also behind /blog/ and I'm not sure on how to do this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to inspect the `%{QUERY_STRING}` as

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)p=1(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^blog/?$ /en/post.html [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)tag=event(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^blog/?$ /en/tags.html [NC,QSA,L]
```

---

To allow any query param values use

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)p= [NC]
RewriteRule ^blog/?$ /en/post.html [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)tag= [NC]
RewriteRule ^blog/?$ /en/tags.html [NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: thanks, how is this done when 1 and event could be anything else as well?